# Tab-delimited file doesn't read correctly, looking for custom split on pandas read

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

I have a large (4+ GB) text file that was *supposed* to be tab-delimited, but something must not have written correctly. When I read it into pandas using the '\t' separator, it reads the rows fine, but jams everything into a single column. Upon inspection of the head(), it looks like some columns are separated by a space, some by 10 spaces, and some at every number of spaced in between. It's all over the place.

It took the team that pulled this data like two weeks to get it to me the first time, so I'm hoping to find a way around the issue. What I would like to do is have the columns broken based on the *first* space after a character, and then have all the other leading and trailing whitespace removed.

So, a file that looks like this:

```
Column1 Column2     Columns3    Column4        Column5
text    date        text        int            text
```

would end up looking like:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
text    date    text    int     text
```

I've tried some regex in the sep:

```python
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(path+"my_file.txt", sep='\s+\-*\s*')
```

But to be honest, I'm not sure if that's doing what I think it is (considering all space sequences as a delimiter, regardless of length), and it hits an error, anyway:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 12 fields in line 5, saw 15. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

So, not sure what to do there, either.

EDIT: Also, as someone pointed out in the comments, it seems that I have variable row lengths when splitting at spaces. Is there a way to read in a file and have the number of columns equal the maximum row length, rather than break if they don't match up to what was read in at first?

It seems I can handle this with pandas.read_fwf, but I'm still curious if there's a way to do it according to the question, in case it comes up again without the benefit of fixed widths.

Comment: Check line 5 in a regex checker and you'll (almost certainly) see that there are more matches than expected. There's probably something in your text columns throwing off your regex. If the data are delimited in a fixed-width way, consider https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: Oh, read_fwf looks great. I did not know that existed, thanks!